# ansible docker mount volumes based on a variable

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-volume

is there a way to mount a volume under `volumes:` directive in ansible docker_service module?

I want to write one docker_compose, and have a variable to choose the correct volume to mount.

```html
- name: Add docker_service for the Ansible Container
    docker_service:
      project_name: jro
      definition:
        version: '3'
        services:
          ansible:  
            image: python:3.7.0a3-alpine3.7
            volumes:
              - {CONDITION xxx} then "xxx:ccc"
              - {CONDITION yyy} then "yyy:ccc:
```

Comment: Apologies Konstantin, see new edited post. Using Ansible module docker_service, see above.

Comment: I think I can use a variable as part of the path, but how to make the condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally for the problem defined in the question:

```
volumes:
   - "{{ 'xxx:ccc' if xxx else omit }}" 
   - "{{ 'yyy:ccc' if yyy else omit }}"
```

<sup>I cannot verify now, if `omit` would work in this particular pattern</sup>

Or (a guess what you might in fact be looking for):

```
volumes:
   - "{{ 'xxx:ccc' if my_condition else 'yyy:ccc' }}"
```

Comment: I tried `omit` and it unfortunately leaves some garbage placeholder :(

Answer (score 4):

That's not how you would typically handle conditionals in an Ansible playbook. You haven't told us what your conditions are, so it's hard to directly answer your question, but you could do something like:

```
- set_fact:
    volume_to_mount: foo
  when: condition1

- set_fact:
    volume_to_mount: bar
  when: condition2

- name: Add docker_service for the Ansible Container
  docker_service:
    project_name: jro
    definition:
      version: '3'
      services:
        ansible:  
          image: python:3.7.0a3-alpine3.7
          volumes:
            - "{{volume_to_mount}}:/mountpoint"
```

If your conditions are hostnames or groups, you would generally handle that through the use of group or host vars files. E.g., if you wanted to mount volume "foo" for all hosts in the "foo_group" hostgroup, and volume "bar" for all hosts in the "bar_group" hostgroup, you would create `group_vars/foo_group.yml` with:

```
volume_to_mount: foo
```

And `groups_vars/bar_group.yml` with:

```
volume_to_mount: bar
```

If you need to mount *multiple* volumes, you would do something similar to the above but using lists instead of single values, e.g.:

```
volumes_to_mount:
  - "bar:/mount_for_bar"
  - "foo:/mount_for_foo"
```

And then in your `docker_service` task:

```
- name: Add docker_service for the Ansible Container
  docker_service:
    project_name: jro
    definition:
      version: '3'
      services:
        ansible:  
          image: python:3.7.0a3-alpine3.7
          volumes: "{{ volumes_to_mount }}"
```

Hopefully something here points you in the right direction.  Feel free to provide more details about what you're trying to do if you'd like a more targeted answer.